# having trouble in redirection URL

Tags: magento-1.9

I've just learnt about magento and i have a trouble with redirection **URL**.

Step 1: go to a page `http://mysecondwebsite.com/news/`.

Step 2: from `http://mysecondwebsite.com/news/` go to `http://mysecondwebsite.com/notebook`. But it goes to `http://mysecondwebsite.com/news/notebook`.

Somebody can tell me why?

Comment: Your server is configured so that all URLs that don't start with `/news/` are redirected to `/news/`. Check your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: ok , i added to hreft `Mage::getBaseUrl()`. It's ok